# What is the purpose of the optional "skipHeaders" parameter within ServiceStack's EndRequest method?

Tags: servicestack

1) What is the purpose of the optional **skipHeaders** parameter within ServiceStack's **EndRequest** method as shown below? Or in other words what happen exactly when **skipHeaders** is **true** or **false**?

```
    this.UncaughtExceptionHandlers.Add((req, res, operationName, ex) => {
         res.Write("Error: {0}: {1}".Fmt(ex.GetType().Name, ex.Message));
         res.EndRequest(skipHeaders: true);
    });
```

2) Is the usage shown below correct (I want to deny requests that comes from a reverse proxy)?

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public sealed class DenyRequestFromReverseProxyAttribute : RequestFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void Execute(IRequest req, IResponse res, object requestDto)
        {
            if (req.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("X-Forwarded-For"))
            {
                res.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
                res.Write("Forbidden - For internal use only.");
                res.EndRequest(skipHeaders: true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It determines whether or not to write the `Config.GlobalResponseHeaders` HTTP Headers. If you've already written to the response stream you want to `skipHeaders:true`.